# Largest range of continuous integers in javascript

Tags: javascript, floating-point

If anyone wants to know...

I was trying to figure out the largest integer that Javavscript could express *that could be part of a continuous range of numbers*. At first, I thought that just using Number.MAX_VALUE would work, but that was a silly assumption.

Javascript stores all numbers as double precision floating point numbers, following the IEEE 754 standard.

Number.MAX_VALUE is equal to

```
7fef ffff ffff ffff, approximately 1.7976931348623157e+308.
```

The next smallest number that can be stored in this format would be

```
7fef ffff ffff fffe, approximately 1.7976931348623155e+308.
```

There is obviously quite a gap inbetween those two numbers that result in behaviors such as

```
Number.MAX_VALUE == (Number.MAX_VALUE-1) //true
```

Now, that doesn't scare me or anything, that's just the matter of fact. What I'm looking for is when this next condition is first true in JS

```
x == (x+1) //true
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather than writing a script that simply added in increments of 1 until the above condition was met, I noticed on the Wikipedia page for IEEE Double-Precision Floating Point the following text:

"Between 2^52=4,503,599,627,370,496 and 2^53=9,007,199,254,740,992 the representable numbers are exactly the integers. For the next range, from 2^53 to 2^54, everything is multiplied by 2, so the representable numbers are the even ones, etc."

So, it seems like 2^53 would be the high-end of the range of continuous integers, and was verified with

```
Math.pow(2,53) == Math.pow(2,53)+1 //true
Math.pow(2,53) == Math.pow(2,53)-1 //false
```

I actually don't need the low end to that range, but it could be interesting if someone knew what it was.

Comment: The range of integers that can be represented exactly in an IEEE `double` is  -2^53+1 to 2^53-1.

Comment: @Joni—I think you're correct, however there are quirks in some browsers at the extremes so the OP should test thoroughly.

Comment: You might want to check [this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744099/is-there-a-good-javascript-bigdecimal-library) if you're doing anything but research into this matter.

Comment: @Joni, wouldn't the largest positive integer that can be represented be 2^53 (rather than 2^53-1) considering the inequality posted in my answer? `Math.pow(2,53) == 9007199254740992` and `Math.pow(2,53)-1 == 9007199254740991`

Comment: But the difference can be shown between 2^53-1 and 2^53, or is the difference shown in the console's output due to rounding?

Comment: Also, in the Wikipedia article it does say that "Between 2^52=4,503,599,627,370,496 and 2^53=9,007,199,254,740,992 are **exactly the integers**." It doesn't say if that range is inclusive or exclusive of 2^53.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "can be represented." 2^53-1 is the greatest integer with a unique representation as double i.e. cannot be confused with another integer when converted to double, and 2^53+1 is the first integer that has no exact representation.

Comment: Okay, well I guess by that I mean that the number can be represented exactly by the IEEE 754 format for double precision floats. In that case, 2^53 **can** be represented exactly as 0x4340000000000000.

Comment: Don't forget that 2^54, 2^55 etc can all be represented exactly.

Comment: But, not in a range of continuous integers that increment by 1 :)